# Is there faster way to find distinct elements using Java

Tags: java

I have written the code to find distinct element in a large array of string. The code is given bellow

```
HashMap<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
String[] str={"aa","bb","cc","bb","aa","cc","aa","bb","cc","bb"};
for (String e : str) {
  if (!countMap.containsKey(e)) {
    countMap.put(e, 1);
  } 
}
Iterator it=countMap.keySet().iterator();
String[] db= new String[countMap.size()];
for(int i=0;i<countMap.size();i++){
  db[i]=(String)it.next();
  System.out.println(db[i]);
}
```

Is there any code faster than this one because I have to process very large array.

Comment: Get rid of the containsKey() test, it's redundant.

Answer (score 5):

This won't be (considerably) faster, but using a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) will definitely be more elegant:

```
String[] str={"aa","bb","cc","bb","aa","cc","aa","bb","cc","bb"};
Set<String> distinct = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str));
for(String s : distinct) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and cooperation

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, I guess HashSet is faster in this scenario. What If we have to maintain the frequency as well, I think in that case HashMap will be better choice since using HashSet we can't maintain frequency. I am just curious to know otherwise my problem is solved.

Comment: If you also need to maintain the frequency, a `HashMap` will be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can parallelize all your work using Java 8:

```
String[] largeArray = null;

Set<String> distinctStrings = 
         Arrays.stream(largeArray).parallel()
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap((s) -> s, (s) -> s)).keySet();
```

This will scale until the contention in the `ConcurrentMap` becomes a problem.

You can also use the `distinct` function on a stream:

```
Set<String> distinctStrings = Arrays.stream(largeArray).parallel()
    .distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

**Microbenchmark**

Both methods running with 1m GUIDs as input (worst case), doing 100 repetitions, measures the time to get a set out of it.

```
Statistics stats = new Statistics();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  String[] largeArray = generate(1_000_000); // generates 1m UUIDs
  Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.createStarted();

  // add the lambda here

  long time = watch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  System.out.println(distinctStrings.size());
  stats.add(time);
}
```

*Note* that this doesn't measure the scalability, you would need to vary the input size for that experiment to get a more accurate sense of what is faster on larger inputs.

**For the `Java Stream Distinct` solution:**

```
[Min=358.0, Max=2236.0, Median=456.0, Mean=542.26, StandardDeviation=335.21174263441304]
```

**For the `ConcurrentMap` solution:**

```
[Min=85.0, Max=1020.0, Median=120.0, Mean=153.58, StandardDeviation=119.78281846742465]
```

**Sequential using `HashSet`**

```
[Min=258.0, Max=1312.0, Median=281.0, Mean=307.39, StandardDeviation=125.63032237481526]
```

**Result**

You get a pretty good speed-up from parallelization, the `ConcurrentMap` solution performs a bit better on that input size than the sequential version (might be different for larger input size / more threads).

The `Stream#distinct` in parallel is slower than the sequential version however.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is the right way. Instead of keeping in `Map` we can prefer `Set`. Internally set using map only.

```
String[] str={"aa","bb","cc","bb","aa","cc","aa","bb","cc","bb"};
HashSet<String> uniques = new HashSet<String>();
for (String string : str) {
    uniques.add(string);
}

String[] result = new String[uniques.size()];
uniques.toArray(result);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```